# C++ Unresolved External Symbols Embedded Lua

Tags: c++, linker, lua

I am trying to make a game with Visual C++ 2010 with an embedded Lua engine, but I keep running into persistent unresolved external symbol errors. I put copies of all the files in the 'include' folder in the project headers folder, and I tried setting the linker library path to the Lua lib folder, as well as setting the include path to the Lua include folder, but I still am getting errors stating that the usage of a couple of Lua core functions are unresolved. I already tried quite a few solutions posted around the internet and each of which resulted in the same errors.

Output:

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pcall referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_loadfile referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_newstate referenced in function _main
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Bubble Wars.h"

extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "luaconf.h"
#include "lua.hpp"
}

int main()
{
    lua_State * L = lua_open();
    luaL_dofile(L,"C:/Users/Trevor/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Bubble Wars/Bubble Wars/Main.lua");
    return 0;
}
```

Main.cpp is the only source file that contains any Lua references. Any reasons for the function references to be unresolved?

Comment: That usually means, that you aren't linking against the '.lib' (alternatively .a) file. Check your makefile to make sure it's being linked too.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium How would I make sure it is being linked to? I am used to just making straight up scripts, mostly in Lua. I am not entirely familiar with IDEs such as Visual C++ yet.

Comment: I'm afraid that's very compiler specific. For Borland, you'd simply 'Add the lib to the project', for a gcc makefile you'd need to add `-llibrarynamehere` (That's not a typo it really needs to be prepended by `-l`.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I found out how to link to the library, linked it, and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you don't have to include `luaconf.h` or `lualib.h`. Also, judging from the file extension, `lua.hpp` is a wrapper around `lua.h` which already contains the `extern "C"` declaration and should not be wrapped in another one. In your case, it is also redundant.

Comment: @mettaursp So how did you do it in the end? I'm also confused as how to link the liblua.a to the VC++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Next to setting the linker directory, you also need to provide the actual libraries to link against to your linker.